# Counting occurrences in a loop

Tags: python

```
gzip_files=["complete-credit-ctrl-txn-SE06_2013-07-17-00.log.gz","complete-credit-ctrl-txn-SE06_2013-07-17-01.log.gz"]

def input_func():
    num = input("Enter the number of MIN series digits: ")
    return num

for i in gzip_files:
    import gzip
    f=gzip.open(i,'rb')
    file_content=f.read()
    digit = input_func()
    file_content = file_content.split('[')
    series = [] #list of MIN
    for line in  file_content:
        MIN = line.split('|')[13:15]
        for x in MIN:
            n = digit
            x = x[:n]
            series.append(x)
            break


    #count the number of occurences in the list named series
    for i in series:
        print i
    #end count
```

Result:

```
63928
63928
63929
63929
63928
63928
```

That is only a part of the result. the actual result shows a really long list. Now i want to just list unique numbers and specify how many times it showed on the list. 
So

```
63928 = 4, 
63929 = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class here.

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(a)
Counter({1: 3, 4: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1})
```

Just pass your `series` variable to `Counter` and you'll get a dictionary where the keys are the unique elements and the values are their occurences in the list.

**collections.Counter** was introduced in Python 2.7. Use the following list comprehension for versions below 2.7

```
>>> [(elem, a.count(elem)) for elem in set(a)]
[(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1)]
```

You can then just convert this into a dictionary for easy access.

```
>>> dict((elem, a.count(elem)) for elem in set(a))
{1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1}
```

Comment: Why does it say that i cant import name Counter?

Comment: What was the exact import statement used? Which Python version are you on?

Comment: Okay. `collections.Counter` was introduced in Python 2.7. Adding an alternative.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Could be his client's choice, or it could be what his hosting provider has (and won't upgrade). I have a client who wanted to use a hosting provider that's on Apache 1.3. *wince*

Comment: @TimPietzcker I dont know. This isnt for my personal use and it just so happens that this is the version the company im interning at is using.

Comment: By the way, I cant get it to work on my code. The code worked by itself but once i added it on my existing code, it doesnt show the occurences list.

Comment: What gets stored in the variable you assigned the `dict(...)` to?

Comment: i am not sure. but i changed a to i. the i which was on the loop for the list of  numbers

Comment: @jeffmangum : Remove the `for i in series: print i` and put this in it's place -> `occurencesDict = dict((elem, series.count(elem)) for elem in set(series))`. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this.

So this will print what you need:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(series)
for item,count in c.items():
    print "%s = %s" % (item,count)
```

Comment: Why does it say that i cant import name Counter?

Answer (score 0):

Compile a dictionary using unique numbers as keys, and their total occurrences as values:

```
d = {} #instantiate dictionary

for s in series:
    # set default key and value if key does not exist in dictionary
    d.setdefault(s, 0)
    # increment by 1 for every occurrence of s
    d[s] += 1
```

If this problem were any more complex. Implementation of `map` `reduce` (aka `map` `fold`) may be appropriate.

**Map Reduce:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

**Python `map` function:**
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

**Python `reduce` function:**
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce